# How to run a x86 based Linux on a ARM processor using virtualization technology?

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, embedded

I have a software which requires CentOS 6.5 (x86). I want to run this software on NXP LS2088ARDB reference board. Porting is becoming increasingly difficult and time consuming. I am thinking of running CentOS 6.5 (x86) as a virtual machine on NXP LS2088ARDB reference board. Can I create it using some Virtualization software similar to vmware or virtualbox?

Comment: you need a specific virtualisation hypervisor that supports hardware emulation of the hardware you want. it's often a bad idea to use a  low performance machine fo emulate another hardware.. qemu does emulation for example

Comment: `QEMU` comes to mind for me also.  Not that I've done this, but that's where I'd look first.  I do have to wonder why you'd want to do this though.  I suspect that if you told people what you're trying to run, and why you're wanting to do it on this board, then you'd get answers suggesting alternative strategies which might work better.

Comment: @mc0e : I am trying to run a third party telecommunication software. The NXP board is a requirement from our customer.

Answer (score 1):

A quick glance of the board's [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/fact-sheet/LS2088ARDBFS.pdf) tells it has `Up to 8 x ARM Cortex®-A72 cores, up to 2.0 GHz core speed`.

You might be able to use QEMU to emulate x86 and run a Linux guest; however, performance might not be very good. Or maybe [qemu user mode emulation](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation) (people have done this to run x86 binaries on Raspberry Pi, which is also ARM) is worth a look. (disclaimer: never tried it).

VirtualBox, VMware etc... will not be useful since they're virtualization software made for x86.